# ASP C# | Update Database using SQL and Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

Here is my OnClick event:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("administratorUpdate", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@originalID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = IDHF.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstNameTB.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastNameTB.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userNameTB.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailAddressTB.Text;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            }
        }
        GetAllRPT.DataBind();
        Label ErrorMessageLabel = (Label)Master.FindControl("ErrorMessageLabel");
        new myFunctions().DisplayUserMessage("success", "Administrator Updated!", ErrorMessageLabel);
        AdminForm.Visible = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label ErrorMessageLabel = (Label)Master.FindControl("ErrorMessageLabel");
        new myFunctions().DisplayUserMessage("error", ex.Message, ErrorMessageLabel);
    }
}
```

Here is my Stored Procedure [administratorUpdate]:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[administratorUpdate]
    @originalID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @firstName varchar (100),
    @lastName varchar (100),
    @userName varchar (100),
    @emailAddress varchar (100),
    @password varchar (100),
    @isActive bit
AS

UPDATE administrator
SET userName = @userName,
    emailAddress = @emailAddress,
    password = @password,
    firstName = @firstName,
    lastName = @lastName,
    isActive = @isActive
WHERE
    ID = @originalID
```

The code executes and does the success message but the datatable doesn't update. Who knows why? I am new to using Stored Procedures in ASP.

Comment: @Raj More Thanks, I didn't know how to format the SQL properly

Comment: Whats with your naming conventions?

Comment: @Phill What do you mean? Camel case?

Comment: 'IDHF.Value' 'firstNameTB.Text' 'administratorUpdate' 'ErrorMessageLabel' 'myFunctions' It's all very inconsistent. txtFirstName, AdministratorUpdate, lblErrorMessage, MyFunctions. The two that stand out most to me is your function class and the server controls.

Comment: @Phill Hmm good point. I will work on that. Thanks!

Comment: some advice...don't take the values you're assigning to your sql parameters directly from the textboxes on the page.  While you're protecting yourself from sql injection, it's still a good idea to assign them to a temp variable and do whatever other validation needs to be done.  Don't do all this work in the click event.  Don't catch Exception, be more specific in your error handling.

Comment: @All Thanks I appreciate it. I am typically a ColdFusion developer but have only done basics in ASP C# using DataSets. I am trying to take knowledge for work and merge it into C#. I would have eventually prevented Sql Injection. But I should probably do it as I go huh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you executing the command?

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        conn.Open(); //this was missing

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("administratorUpdate", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@originalID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = IDHF.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstNameTB.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastNameTB.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userNameTB.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailAddressTB.Text;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //this was missing.
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Also need to open the connection to the database by doing con.Open(); before doing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @Dismissile I thought when I am using 'using' it's open whilest the data is in that statement. I can pull data down, but sending data i guess is different?

Comment: That too. I have modified the answer with the proper implementation.

Comment: @Babak Don't I have to close it?

Comment: @Bry4n, yes you are correct. My main point was that you're not executing.

Comment: You don't have to close the connection explicitly. The using statement will close the connection for you...but it does not open it.The using statement will automatically call Dispose() if your class implements IDisposable. Close() just calls Dispose()

Answer (score 1):

My trick here is to do this in debug mode without the Try / Catch. The error(s) generated will point to the problem.